# Uniform SQL Date in Oracle SQL and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ansi-sql

Like the title indicates, I'm trying to make an uniform query, which has compatible syntax for Oracle SQL and for SQL Server

The current syntax I have is written in Oracle and is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
WHERE CREATION_DATE = TO_DATE('12-09-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

When I try to build this in SQL Server, this doesn't work. The syntax of SQL Server is

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA 
WHERE OrderDate='12-09-2015'
```

But this doesn't work in Oracle SQL...

So what is the uniform way to write this?

Comment: Is there a reason that you would want to use literals in the first place?  Rather than using bind variables so that you can use whatever `date` class exists in whatever language you are building your application in?

Comment: +1 for Justin Cave's suggestion. It's far safer to use parameterized queries with date-typed parameters, not only to avoid localization issued but for security and performance reasons as well. BTW in SQL Server the invariant date format is `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: Bind variables are best when they can be used, but that's not all the time. Sometimes you need hard coded dates to encode business rules e.g. tax rates change on a certain date, the way some ID or reference number is calculated changes based on date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for something which works on both:

```
CAST('2015-09-14' as date)
```

The cast is executed only once so has no effect on performance.

Comment: @Guil: Then you were lucky. It doesn't work in Oracle if you don't happen to use some regional setting where '2015-09-14' is an accepted date representation. It definitely doesn't work on my machine set to German. (I am getting ORA-01861.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, that appears not to comply with SQL92, which requires character strings with the same format as a date literal to be accepted. Odd.

Comment: This only works in oracle if NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to `yyyy-mm-dd`, which shouldn't be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if SQL Server supports **ANSI DATE literal**, but it is supported in Oracle. The default string literal format is **YYYY-MM-DD**.

```
DATE '2015-09-12'
```

so, if ANSI standard is supported in SQL Server too, then use it. It is simple.

Based on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb630352.aspx), I think you could use the above in both the databases.

> WHERE OrderDate='12-09-2015'

Never do that. You are comparing a **DATE** with a **STRING**, you might be just lucky to get correct data depending on your **locale-specific NLS settings**. But, never rely on **implicit data type conversion**.

Comment: I tried it and it worked on Oracle, but on SQL Server I get: Error: Incorrect syntax near '2015-09-12'.
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 102

Comment: SqlServer uses YYYYMMDD, i.e. '20150912'

Comment: Not sure this is correct even for Oracle. SQL Server understands the *full* datetime ISO format, ie including the time element. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_year-day-month_.28YDM.29) Kazakhstan still uses a YDM format. It's possible both databases can encounter problems with older clients

Comment: @Guil that's because you need to use the full ISO format, including the time element. Otherwise you can use the unseparated date format, ie YYYYMMDD. Don't know if Oracle supports this

Comment: Oracle definitely supports it. It depends on the format model, that's it. If you do not have time element, then just use pure ANSI date literal `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD`. For datetime, Oracle has `TO_DATE` function, which could be used depending on the format model and the values. For example, `TO_DATE('2015-09-12 13:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`. Since OP is only concerned about the date portion, and not the time portion, I suggested the ANSI date literal.

Comment: @LalitKumarB the point is to use an *unambiguous* format, ie one that *isn't* affected by the language. SQL Server also supports YYYY-MM-DD but it *is* affected by the language. If Oracle is affected as well, then `YYYY-MM-DD` isn't suitable

Comment: @Panagiotis Oracle doesn't work that way. A date doesn't have any format in Oracle, it is internally stored in 7 bytes which is Oracle's proprietary format. The format model that you see is only for display purpose or while converting a lieral into date.

Comment: @LalitKumarB You missed the point. SQL Server has no "format" either. Here we are talking about *string literals*. In SQL Server, the *date-only literal* `2015-09-08` is affected by the language format. The only format *for date-only literals* guaranteed to be unaffected is `YYYYMMDD`. If you want to use the ISO format, you need to specify the time element as well *with the T*, ie `2015-09-08T15:00:00`